# Run a Django project from VSCODE

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to run a Django project from VSCODE editor?

Currently I use the windows CMD to run my project. Every time when I hit the button 'run' on VSCODE it doesn't run the project.

On pyCharm we can add 'runserver' to its script parameters configurations. Is there something like that on VSCODE?

**UPDATE**

I'm getting this on VSCODE terminal:

```
Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[auth]
    changepassword
    createsuperuser

[contenttypes]
    remove_stale_contenttypes

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    sendtestemail
    shell
    showmigrations
    sqlflush
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    test
    testserver

[sessions]
    clearsessions

[staticfiles]
    collectstatic
    findstatic
    runserver

[Done] exited with code=0 in 9.449 seconds
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I did:
From Terminal -> Configure Tasks...

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Django: Run Server",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "args":[ 
               "manage.py",
               "runserver"
         ],
        "group": "none",
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "always",
            "panel": "new"
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

Afterwards, it should show up, when you select Terminal -> Run Task...

Comment: So, did you select Terminal -> Configure Tasks -> "create tasks.json file from template" then selected one of the three: MSBuild/maven/.NET core? Which did you select?

Comment: Yeah you are to select "create task.json file from template" and then select "others create abitrary file". A new file called task.json will be created in .vscode, this is where you ill paste the above dictionary/json data.

Answer (score 3):

I'm in Linux if you are different environment please provide approprite command

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `p` and type >`python: Select Interpreter` Please select your virtualenv which Django installed.

And Go to Debug ( `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `d` ) and these...

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/manage.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput",
                "DjangoDebugging"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I still can't run the project directly from the VSCODE. I updated the question to show what I'm getting on VSCODE terminal.

Comment: It's should work because I'm using this snippet in my computer

Comment: But the question is how to run, not debug.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to update the changes in VS Code, you can run the command in the Windows terminal:

- Step 1: Activate the virtual environment (if you are using it)
- Step 2: Point the directory where manage.py is located and then run the `runserver` command and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I use VS Code and run the project typing `python manage.py runserver` and everything works smoothly. I'm not aware of having done anything special to make it work this way.
I do work wihin a pip virtual env that i launch by typing `pipenv shell`.

Whenever i run `python manage.py runserver` it launches the server at 127.0.0.1:8000.

I assumed it came built-in with django. Maybe it has something to do with how you installed python. I remember having some issue with that some time back. It was about setting the PATH variable in the windows environment.